# Simple thread in c# not working as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am following [this screencast on multithreading](https://youtu.be/RhLLxew4-TY?list=PLhq7kqloVlM897pJ9TdVHVRo5stL_LlMu) .

The video in min 12:13 says that the program is supposed to run loop on thread with name t and then run the code from the main thread. So in the output I should see ThreadProc 0 - 9, then 4 times message from the main thread - right opposite what I have know.

Question is what is wrong. The code looks similar according to screencast.

The code:

> ```
> namespace Objective_1._1 {
>
>
>    internal class Program
>
> {
>     public static void ThreadMethod()
>     {
>         for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc {0}", i);
>             Thread.Sleep(0);
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>         var t = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
>         t.Start();
>
>         // Loop on the main thread
>         for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Main thread: Do some work");
>             Thread.Sleep(0);
>         }
>
>        //Do not pass this line of code and exit the main until thread t finish
>         t.Join();
>     }
> } }
> ```

When user runs it, then the result is as follows:

[image]

EDIT

Result with

> Thread.Sleep(5)

in the main.

[image]

EDIT 2

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: change the sleep in main to sleep(5) - just to see

Comment: You need to do a non-zero sleep on the main thread after starting the sub-thread to allow it to run first.  It's probably more interesting if you have a longer sleep time in your loops though.

Comment: using sleep in application usualy means the threading is poorly thought out to begin with, but if you MUST; use .sleep(1) as sleep(0) is problematic.

Comment: it the video there is sleep 0 on both threads.And if I change sleep in the main thread on 5, still do not have expected result according to the screencast.

Comment: you should not expect to see the messages in any order - it is highly dependent on workstation vs server, OS version , .Net version, machine power, concurrent load,....

Comment: jmod - are you sure the t.Join() in your code is in the same place as in the screencast you are referring to? If you put it before the loop in the main thread, the output should be what you expect.

Comment: with thread.sleep(5) I was running the code 4 times in a row, and always had the the second result - see my edit.

Comment: I pasted the code into LinqPad and ran it a dozen times. It produced different output each time. That's how threading works, it's non-deterministic when each thread will get processor time.

Comment: user469104 yes I am sure, see my edit, screen from the screencast.

Comment: I'd suggest using another source to learn threading from - this presenter doesn't seem to be a credible source.

Comment: jmod999 - Well then the screencast is wrong :) Wrong in the sense that the code as written would not consistently/predictably produce the exact same output.

Comment: Why would you even put Thread.Sleep(0) ever unless you were putting that line of code in there to show off how the proc messages change when you change the number? As was said previously, the order in which they pop up does not matter. The point that is being demonstrated is that they are both running simultaneously.

Comment: ok thanks, so I am going to change the source.Btw do you have some good recommendations on this topic???

Comment: Maybe the guy did a bad job of explaining what was going on (I don't know, I didn't watch the video), but it seems to me as though the code successfully demonstrates how multithreading works. I would try changing the sleep to 1000 so you can see what is actually happening instead of using these low numbers that don't clearly demonstrate what's going on. What you expect to see is the two messages popping up back and forth as each thread runs its own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing multithreading, there is no guarantee what order threads will run without giving a thread a higher priority over another.  Just because your want your thread to run first then the main thread to finish, IMO, defeats the purpose of multithreading.  You may as well not have spawned a thread to begin with.  Like Yair Nevet states, the main thread just keeps running before your thread initializes and starts.  For "true" multithreading, I would have expected your outputs to be mingled, but again that is not guaranteed like pm100 commented.

Now to answer your question about making the Thread finish before the main thread, move your Thread.Join() above the for loop in the main thread and you'll get the expected output that you want.

Answer (score 0):

> So in the output I should see ThreadProc 0 - 9, then 4 times message
>   from the main thread - right opposite what I have know.

You first see the writes from the main thread because the time to initialise the child thread takes a while and starts later - In parallel, the main thread is keep running and doing its operations.